# Regex - Match URLs which contain 1 or 2 of these words but not all 3

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am building a regular expression for Google Analytics and I'm almost there, but I'm stuck at the last part.

I am trying to match specific words in the URL, regardless of their order, but I want to exclude URLs which contain 3 specific words together.

Here are 4 URLs:

```
/find-store?radius=30&manufacturers=sony,phillips,magnavox&segment=residential&postal=998028#
/find-store?search=Juneau%2C+AK+99802%2C+USA&radius=30&manufacturers=sony,magnavox&segment=commercial&postal=998028#
/find-store?radius=30&manufacturers=phillips,sony&segment=residential&postal=998028#
/find-store?radius=30&manufacturers=magnavox&segment=residential&postal=998028#
```

I want my regex to match all of the above URLs except for the first one(which contains sony, phillips and magnavox). The brands can be in different order so it needs to check if those 3 words exist regardless of the order.

Here is my current regex which matches all of those URLs:

```
(find-store.*sony.*magnavox)|(find-store.*sony.*phillips)|(find-store.*sony)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex works.  `^(?!(?=.*sony)(?=.*phillips)(?=.*magnavox)).+$`

```
 ^                          # BOS
 (?!                        # Cannot be all three on the line
      (?= .* sony )
      (?= .* phillips )
      (?= .* magnavox )
 )
 .+ 
 $                          # EOS
```

And for specific phrases  `^(?!(?=.*sony)(?=.*phillips)(?=.*magnavox)).*find-store.*$`

```
 ^                          # BOS
 (?!                        # Cannot be all three on the line
      (?= .* sony )
      (?= .* phillips )
      (?= .* magnavox )
 )
 .* 
 find-store                 # Add sepcific phrase/words
 .* 
 $                          # EOS
```

You can also put the specific phrase at the top

```
 # ^.*?find-store(?!(?=.*sony)(?=.*phillips)(?=.*magnavox)).+$

 ^                          # BOS
 .*? 
 find-store                 # Add sepcific phrase/words

 (?!                        # Cannot be all three on the line
      (?= .* sony )
      (?= .* phillips )
      (?= .* magnavox )
 )
 .+ 
 $                          # EOS
```

And if you require a sony, phillips or magnovox, you can add them at the bottom.

```
 # ^.*?find-store(?!(?=.*sony)(?=.*phillips)(?=.*magnavox)).*?(sony|phillips|magnavox).*?$

 ^                                  # BOS
 .*? 
 find-store                         # Add required sepcific phrase/words

 (?!                                # Cannot be all three on the line
      (?= .* sony )
      (?= .* phillips )
      (?= .* magnavox )
 )
 .*? 
 ( sony | phillips | magnavox )     # (1), Required. one of these
 .*? 
 $                                  # EOS
```

Comment: Are negative lookaheads supported in GA? You might need to verify that.

Comment: @user13286 - No problem. I don't know GA. So, if assertions like this aren't supported, this probably won't work.

Comment: @sln I tested it [using a tool](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester) that is marketed as being specifically for GA, and it worked perfectly, so I think we're good. Thanks again!

Comment: @user13286  - Great !!